# Independence of sum and difference of two independent standard normal random variables. Why?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, normal-distribution, independence, orthogonal-matrices

> **Proposition**: Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent and normally distributed with zero expectation
> and variance $\sigma^2 > 0$. Then $X_1 + X_2$ and $X_1 − X_2$ are independent and normally
> distributed with expectation $0$ and variance $2\sigma^2$.
> **Proof**: The vector $(X_1/\sigma,X_2/\sigma)^T$ is standard Gaussian by assumption. Look at
> $$A =\begin{pmatrix}
> \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&
> \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\
> \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
> \end{pmatrix}$$
> This is an orthogonal matrix and applying it to our vector yields $((X_1+X_2)/(\sqrt{2}\sigma), (X_1−
> X_2)/(\sqrt{2}\sigma))$, $\color{red}{\text{ which thus must have independent standard normal coordinates}}$.

The fact that $X_1+X_2\sim\mathbb{N}(0,2\sigma^2)$ and $X_1-X_2\sim\mathbb{N}(0,2\sigma^2)$ sounds clear to me.
My doubt regards the $\color{red}{\text{ red part}}$ in the proof:
 why, once that I have the vector $((X_1+X_2)/(\sqrt{2}\sigma), (X_1−
X_2)/(\sqrt{2}\sigma))$, as a consequence of all the provided info such a vector *"must have independent standard normal coordinates"*? That is - if I properly understand - why can I say that $X_1+X_2\perp \!\!\! \perp  X_1-X_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the first vector $v$: its joint log-PDF is $-\ln(2\pi)-\tfrac12v\cdot v=-\ln(2\pi)-\tfrac12v_1^2-\tfrac12v_2^2$. The orthogonal transformation preserves this, so it's still linearly separable, implying independence of the new variables. That the PDF is unchanged also establishes $\tfrac{X_1\pm X_2}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\sim N(0,\,1)$ (note you shouldn't have placed the $\sigma$ under the $\sqrt{}$).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I have just edited the question. Unfortunately, I am not very comfortable with linear algebra by now. Could you please give me some reference for the orthogonal transformation preservation? @J.G.

Comment: @Strictly_increasing All we're using is $(Au)^TAv=u^T\underbrace{A^TA}_{I}v=u^Tv$, so that $Au\cdot Av=u\cdot v$.

Comment: So, in my case: 
$$a=(X_1/\sigma,X_2/\sigma)$$
$$B =\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}$$
So:
$$Ba=c=((X_1+X_2)/(\sqrt{2}\sigma), (X_1−
X_2)/(\sqrt{2}\sigma))$$
Notice that:
$$(Ba)^T\cdot Ba\overbrace{=}^{\text{$B$ orthogonal}}a^T\cdot a$$

Hence, I can conclude that $c$ must have independent standard normal coordinates, just like $a$, because of orthogonal transformation (which preserves the coordinates properties, **including independence, which is the fact I am most interested in**, right?) @J.G.

Comment: @Strictly_increasing That's it, yes.